# How to apply custom maya manipulator with user defined context

Tags: python, maya

I'm learning maya scripting from recent days and got confused about how to apply custom manipulator with user defined context. Select the obj and click `Show Manipulator Tool` doesn't work. This question maybe stupid but I just cannot find out how to do it.

There is an example in the devkit `filmMoveManip.py` and I wanna know how to use it. I know how to load it, just the way how to get the manipulator shown and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the script [filmMoveManip](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/api/film_move_manip_8py-example.html).py to your plugin_path and follow the usage guide in the file header:

```
# filmMoveManip.py
#       Scripted plug-in that displays a manipulator that 
#       modifies the film translate horizontal and vertical
#       values. 
#
# To use this plug-in:
# 1. execute the following Python:
# import maya
# maya.cmds.loadPlugin("filmMoveManip.py")
# maya.cmds.spFilmMoveManipCtxCmd( 'spFilmMoveManipContext1' )
# maya.cmds.setParent( 'Shelf1' )
# maya.cmds.toolButton( 'spFilmMoveManip1', cl='toolCluster', t='spFilmMoveManipContext1', i1="filmMoveManip.xpm" )
# 2. Open the outliner and select a camera shape such as perspShape
# 3. A manipulator with a horizontal and vertical axis will be displayed.
# 4. Move the axis to modify the film translate
```